# Control redirect after create in certain circumstances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have a rails app that has multiple ways of creating tasks

a) A normal task new screen with lots of options

b) A quick task create screen which has the minimum actions and only has the minimum fields to enable quick creation. And a list of the actions

After the create succeeds I want

a) to redirect to the standard show form

b) to redirect back to the quick edit page with a blank quick creation box and the new task in the list.

If create fails on validation I want

a) to redirect to the edit screen with the fields highlighted

b) to redirect to the quick create screen with the fields highlighted and the data still there.

I've tried editing the create respond_to if.save? but that seems to apply to everything in both cases.

There's a slight complication in that I create tasks either generically (no client selected) or as a nested route under client where the client is autoselected, and ideally I'd like to go back to that nested route location.

I'd like to control that respond to by using an if parameter that recognises where the call is coming from

```
if from quick_create
  if @task.save?
    redirect
  else
    reload table and clear
if from new
  if task.save?
```

Any ideas?

Adding current controller code and routes:

```
routes.rb

get 'tasks/quick_create' => 'tasks#quick_create'
-----
resources :clients do
    match 'tasks/quick_create' => 'tasks#quick_create'
----
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])
    @task.practice_id = current_user.practice_id
    unless @task.recurring.present?
      @task.build_recurring
    end
    @task.create_recurring_tasks

    if  params[:batch_task] == "Create Task"
      @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
      @task.build_batch_task(@client)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def quick_create
    if params[:client_id]
      @client = Client.find(params[:client_id]).tasks
      @tasks = @client.accessible_by(current_ability, :read).order(:due_date)
    else
      @tasks = Task.accessible_by(current_ability, :read).order(:due_date)
    end
    @task = Task.new
    @task.status = "Not Complete"
    #@task.task_files.build
    @task.build_recurring

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @tasks }
    end
  end
```

Ibasically want to control the respond do bit with something like

```
if request.path.include? "quick_create"
```

And be able to flag up the errors on quick create. There appears to be two things. 
1. The request.path if statement doesn't work
2. The @task when attempting to feed back to the quick_create page hits an error (since it expects both @task and @tasks, I think).

Anyway....

Comment: create two controllers or different actions to split the two unrelated methods.

Comment: I have separate action method in the controller for quick create, but when it creates it's still using the standard create method (which I supposed is probably sensible as there will be some nice underlying rails magic there). I don't mind that, but I do want it to redirect to the right place afterwards. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine You may have two options -

- specify some custom parameter inside URL and use it to decide where redirect to
- or use different actions as already suggested.

If You are having problems with two different create actions, post current controller code and Your routes otherwise we can't help You.